# How can i get metrics from Bitly API with custom date range?

Tags: api, enums, python-requests, bitly

I have been trying to use Bitly API.
This is the [documentation](https://dev.bitly.com/api-reference#getClicksForBitlink) I have been following.

I am trying to call a GET request over  */v4/bitlinks/{bitlink}/clicks* as shown in the above documentation.

```
params = {
    'unit' : 'day',
    'units' : -1
}
response = requests.get(f'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks/{domain}/2MIHzhO/clicks', headers=headers, params=params)
```

gives me 30 results i.e. for the last month (30 day wise entries).
However I was expecting more entries beyond that.

If i use `units=40` instead, I get the following error with code 402

```
{'message': 'UPGRADE_REQUIRED',
 'resource': 'bitlinks',
 'description': 'Metrics request exceeds maximum queryable date range.'}
```

Is there a limit to the date range I can query because it is not explicitly stated in the API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your guess is right. There is a limit to the date range you can query in bitly free plan - the link history limit is 30 days. That's why you get this error message when trying to query for metrics for 40 days.
You can find different bitly plans info [here](https://bitly.com/pages/pricing?utm_content=site-knowledgbase&utm_source=organic&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=upgrade-cta&utm_cta=web-blank-knowledgebase-header-pricing-pricing-webpricing)